# varchar not being displayed as multiline in html

Tags: html, mysql

I have a HTML form that is multiple rows and inserts multiline text onto a SQL VARCHAR field. The value is correctly store in the SQL table with multiple lines, however when I try to display it in HTML the formatting is not multiple lines.
Example:

```
Multi
Line 
Test
```

Becomes - `Multi Line Test`

My HTML code is:

```
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($aboutme); ?></p>
```

I do not have any CSS formatting that effects the paragraph tag.

Comment: "Multi Line Test" becomes "Multi Line Test" whats the difference?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php?

Comment: As it is a relatively large amount of text that will be intered - ~4000 characters, having proper paragraph formatting is relatively important.

Comment: nl2br solved the problem.

Comment: @dominicansell if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27569313/3000179) solved your question, it would be sensible to [mark it accepted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) to close your question and show others what helped you, should they have the same/similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML uses `<br>` to indicate a new line, But your data probably uses `\n` as line ending. So if I'm correct, your data in the database is stored as `Multi\nLine\nTest`

You can try the [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to convert the new line endings:

```
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars(nl2br($aboutme)); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try str_replace()

if your variable is $aboutme

make it

```
    $aboutme = str_replace(" ","<br>",$aboutme);
```

Maybe nl2br($des) also works

```
   $aboutme = nl2br($aboutme);
```

But I Prefer the first approach

Comment: your first approach replaces all spaces with a <br>. To make it work you should use str_replace("\n", "<br>", $des). But the nl2br method does exactly the same thing :)